# Does H5Eset_auto2() need to be called for every file created

Tags: c++, hdf5

I am trying to expand the error logging from HDF5 into the general application error logging so I call `H5Eset_auto2(H5E_DEFAULT, customErrorHandler, nullptr)`.

If the first file I open for reading has an error, the custom handler is trigger and logs the error as expected. If the first file reads without error, but the second file contains an error, the custom handler is not triggered and the default HDF5 handler prints the error stack to stderr.

If I call `H5Eset_auto2(H5E_DEFAULT, customErrorHandler, nullptr)` each time I open a file, the custom handler is triggered as expected.

I can't find in the documentation where the error handler is reset for each file (or hid) opened. This also doesn't help in the cases where I get an error when creating a custom type before opening a file. Am I using the custom error handlers incorrectly? Is there a way to setup an error handler globally for all objects?

HDF5 version 1.14.1
Using the c style interface, but in a c++ application